# Unable to open up port 80 on EC2 using elasticfox

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have launched an instance of EC2. Initially the security group I created did not have the port 80 open. I sshed and installed Apache etc, and now want to open port 80. I am using elasticfox.

So I

1. go to Security Group - > [My Group name] - > Grant new permission
2. Open up the port 80(Http with TCP) for network range 0.0.0.0/0

Now my assumption is that these ports should be opened up on the instance, but the instance is not responding on the allocated IPs, public DNS entry. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a windows instance, then you also need to open the port on that instance's individual firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a RedHat instance, which has port 80 blocked in the firewall config by default.

run the following command and enable www/http/80 in the firewall config:
system-config-firewall-tui